# LINQ split string into sentences dependently to quotes

Tags: c#, linq, text

How to split text into sentences in a text; with dots, question marks, exclamation marks etc. I'm trying to get every sentence one by one except inside of quotes.

For example split this:

```
Walked. Turned back. But why? And said "Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!" without a shame.
```

Like this:

```
Walked. 
Turned back. 
But why? 
And said "Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!" without a shame.
```

I'm using this code:

```
 private List<String> FindSentencesWhichContainsWord(string text, string word)
        {
            string[] sentences = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // Define the search terms. This list could also be dynamically populated at runtime.
            string[] wordsToMatch = { word };

            // Find sentences that contain all the terms in the wordsToMatch array.
            // Note that the number of terms to match is not specified at compile time.
            var sentenceQuery = from sentence in sentences
                                let w = sentence.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' },
                                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                where w.Distinct().Intersect(wordsToMatch).Count() == wordsToMatch.Count()
                                select sentence;

            // Execute the query. Note that you can explicitly type
            // the iteration variable here even though sentenceQuery
            // was implicitly typed. 

            List<String> rtn = new List<string>();
            foreach (string str in sentenceQuery)
            {
                rtn.Add(str);
            }
            return rtn;
        }
```

But it's giving the result below which is not I wish.

```
Walked. 
Turned back. 
But why? 
And said "Hello world.
Damn this string splitting things!
" without a shame.
```

Comment: You have `'!'` char in your `Split` array

Comment: You could test your string if the dots, exclamation marks, etc. are inside quotation marks and then jump over the split function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem can be solved in two steps:

1. Using `TextFieldParser` to correctly identify the quoted words

   ```
   string str = "Walked. Turned back. But why? And said \"Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!\" without a shame.";
   string[] words = null;
   using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(str))){
       parser.Delimiters = new string[] { " " };
       parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
       words = parser.ReadFields();                
   }
   ```
2. Using the earlier result to customize the new array of `string` based on your desired special behavior.

   ```
   List<string> newWords = new List<string>();
   string accWord = "";
   foreach (string word in words) {
       if (word.Contains(" ")) //means this is multiple items
           accWord += (accWord.Length > 0 ? " " : "") + "\"" + word + "\"";
       else {
           accWord += (accWord.Length > 0 ? " " : "") + word;
           if (word.EndsWith(".") || word.EndsWith("!") || word.EndsWith("?")) {
               newWords.Add(accWord);
               accWord = "";
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Result `newWords`:

```
[2016-01-28 08:29:48.534 UTC] Walked.
[2016-01-28 08:29:48.536 UTC] Turned back.
[2016-01-28 08:29:48.536 UTC] But why?
[2016-01-28 08:29:48.536 UTC] And said "Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!" without a shame.
```

If needed be, you could simply wrap those two in a single method returning `List<string>`

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I didn't know the `TextFieldParser` yet.

Comment: @t3chb0t It is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` `namespace`. Normally used to handle CSV file actually. :) check it out!

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk it is normally used for CSV file, but you could change the delimiters the way it suits your need. One best thing about it is it can recognize quotation mark! :) In my example, in the first part, I split the text by `space`. And all the words will be split by space **except those which are in the quotation mark**. And then in my second part, I rearrange the words again. :) you could print `words` in the example above to check how `TextFieldParser` actually works too. Then you will get clearer picture... :)

Comment: @Ian After I try to implement this on my code I saw this is not what I exactly want because splitting with spaces is not a good starting point since texts and using of punctuations are not perfect, actually generally it's really far from perfect. So I don't think this is the best solution for me. Yes it works but only on standard conditions.

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk that sounds pretty bad... :( but perhaps you could give more samples of your inputs-outputs? We can only think of fitting solution if there is any real cases, I think. The solution I gave to you was only meant for the given examples - It is true that I do not fully know how you are going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a thing called a "sentence splitter". It's not a trivial problem...

If you're interested in how to correctly solve these kinds of problems, I'd recommend the book "Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing" from Manning and Schutze.

To give you an impression of how complex this is, I'll briefly describe the sentence splitter that we use at Nubilosoft as part of our search components.

- First we do paragraph splitting. By doing that, we're eliminating some obvious errors and it makes our text smaller. Most file formats like MS Word DOC(X) and HTML already provide paragraph markers, making this a good first step.
- Next, we do feature extraction on the text. Features are things like punctuation marks, some common abbreviations (like 'dr.') and some context information.
- We determine split points. Split points are punctuations and characters that change case. (people sometimes forget punctuation marks).
- Finally, we feed it all to a perceptron neural network, which then determines if something is a 'split' location.

Everything here is trained and tested on a manually annotated corpus; I cannot remember the exact numbers, but it's quite a lot of sentences.

By doing it like that, it's approximately 99% correct, which is "more then good enough" for our purposes.

Note that licensing of corpora is quite a tricky business... In the past, I found that the easiest way to get yourself a properly working sentence splitter is to simply buy one that is already trained.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the same way with your walkthrough except the second and fourth step but it's already enough complex to do this alone and questionable to make an effort for this in my situation. I'm trying to get all sentences in a text and make words selectable one by one for operators and these selection will feed an application. Thanks for detailed info. I'm glad to hear this topic is deep enough to make it systematic. By the way I doubt if this book is multilingual or not.

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk We have most NLP tools for over a dozen languages. The statistics of most languages is similar, but you do need different rules for each language such as tokens, abbreviations, etc. The book describes the foundations, not implementation details. PS: word splitting is called tokenization, which is also quite challenging.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a *bullet-proof* solution but it could be implemented like this. I did the sentence and quote recognition by hand

```
void Main()
{
    var text = "Walked. Turned back. But why? And said \"Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!\" without a shame.";
    var result = SplitText(text);
}

private static List<String> SplitText(string text)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var sentenceEndings = new HashSet<char> { '.', '?', '!' };

    var startIndex = 0;
    var length = 0;

    var isQuote = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = text[i];
        if (c == '"' && !isQuote)
        {
            isQuote = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (c == '"' && isQuote)
        {
            isQuote = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (!isQuote && sentenceEndings.Contains(c))
        {
            length = i + 1 - startIndex;
            var part = text.Substring(startIndex, length);
            result.Add(part);
            startIndex = i + 2;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used TakeWhile. take until the character is not separator. or if it was inside quotes.

```
var seperator = new[] {'.', '?', '!'};

string str =
    @"Walked. Turned back. But why? And said ""Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!"" without a shame.";

List<string> result = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
bool quotes = false;
while (index < str.Length)
{
    var word = str.Skip(index).TakeWhile(ch =>
    {
        index++;
        if (ch == '"') quotes = !quotes;
        return quotes || !seperator.Contains(ch);
    });

    result.Add(string.Join("", word).Trim());
}
```

Comment: Output is: `Walked
Turned back
But why
And said "Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!" without a shame`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the shortest way I've seen but it's not taking the punctuations at the end of sentences. Well I can take one more letter but maybe there is an easier fix.

Comment: It's not complete solution this way, I can't accept I'm sorry. I will follow another way.